# Unable to download the bitmap to a target using Picasso?

Tags: android, picasso

I am trying to load the bitmaps to an arraylist as follows:

```
 Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(new Target(){

        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            //mainLayout.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap));
            photos.add(bitmap);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(final Drawable errorDrawable) {
            Log.d("TAG", "FAILED");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(final Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Prepare Load");
        }
    });
```

But why is the onBitmapLoaded method never called?

Comment: in my case is calling

Answer (score 0):

Picasso, doesn't hold strong references to `new Target()` it will be garbage collected

look over [this](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/669#issuecomment-56842469)